# Эвфонитеская вставка, формант

Tags: историческое-словообразование

Является ли эвфоническая вставка формантом?

Answer (score 2):

Смотря что Вы имеете в виду. В любом случае -Н- не является отдельным аффиксом.

Если -н- между предлогом и корнем (с ним), то есть вот такое мнение:

> В некоторых комбинациях приставок/предлогов и корней имеется
>   эвфоническая вставка н, которую с лёгкой руки И. А. Бодуэна де Куртенэ
>   принято считать частью праформ *sъn, *vъn, *kъn. А. Вайан даже не
>   рассматривает такую гипотезу. Она объясняет только 15 случаев из 32 в
>   старославянском и даёт ошибочное предсказание в 18 других случаях.

.   http://xn--80afqvalc3ae5i.xn--c1avg/w/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8

По крайней мере, в слове от/ня/ть, от/ним/ать вставка входит в корень.